# jquery load div when img loaded from script

Tags: jquery, image, load

This code is working when img src is already set, like :

```
<div id="images">
<img src="something.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#images").hide();
        $("div#images").find("img").load(function(){
            $(this).closest("div#images").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working if images src is calling a script :

```
<img src="getimage.php?img=something.jpg" />
```

In getimage.php I do echo readfile($_GET["img"]);

How can I make this work?

Patrick

Comment: Can you try this: in your browser navigate to: "getimage.php?img=something.jpg", can you see the image?

Comment: Use the jQuery `load` function.

Comment: I've tried the load function, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893908/jquery-div-when-all-images-loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the SRC attribute you can you JQuery's `attr()` function:

```
$("#myImg").attr("src","newImage.png");
```

Comment: OK, how would I applied this?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. When you need to fetch a new image instead of the existing one you use the method the way I demonstrated. that is, you can have an hidden IMG element with empty SRC attribute, that will be manipulated via JS

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready`.

`$(document).ready` happens when the html is ready, while  `window.onload` happens after the images and the contend have been loaded.

I think that the problem whith your code is that when any of the images inside the `div` "div#images" is loaded, then the function that displays that same `div` is called, even if the other images haven't been loaded yet.

You could try to hide the "div#images" on `$(document).ready` and display it on `window.onload`.

Comment: I've tried it. But it's not working because $(window).load() runs later, after the image data is loaded as well.

Comment: Try to hide the "div#images" on $(document).ready and display it on window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

That's what I did :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div#images").hide();
var $images = $('div#images img');
var loaded_images_count = 0;
$images.load(function(){
    loaded_images_count++;
    if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
        $("div#images").show();
    }
});
</script>
```