# jquery div when all images loaded

Tags: jquery, image, load

I can load an image when it is loaded, by doing:

```
<img style="display:none;" src="big3.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('img').load(function(){
        $(this).css({'display':'block'})
    });
</script>
```

But what I want is to load the div when all img is loaded, but this is not working, why? :

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <img src="big3.jpg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').load(function(){
        $(this).css({'display':'block'})
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.css()`? `.show()` works just fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As @Kolink said, divs don't load. This code will show the div when all the images inside the div have loaded. (untested)

```
var $images = $('div img');
var loaded_images_count = 0;

$images.load(function(){
    loaded_images_count++;

    if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
        $("div").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: For those using more recent versions of jQuery, be sure to change this to `$images.on('load', function(){`

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` elements don't load, images do. You want to listen for when the image loads, and then get the `<div>` and show it.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer this question but for anyone viewing this thread, there is a simple and easy to use jQuery plugin with lots of other tricks to do the job. [You can check it out here](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/).
then for checking all image load, you just need to do this

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded()
  .always( function( instance ) {
    console.log('all images loaded');
  })
```