# Detect images loaded in bootstrap modal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on my page for open bootstrap modal with thousands of images in unordered list like this: `ul > li.thumbnail > img.image`. I need to show a fullscreen loader after modal is opened and hide loader after images are loaded. But there is not strict count of `li` elements. Do you have any idea how can I do this? Thank you!

//EDIT

but I dont need to load it on full page load, I want to load it on modal open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery div when all images loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893908/jquery-div-when-all-images-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution

```
var loader = $('#loading'); //fullscreen loading animation
$("#lg-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        loader.css({ 'display': 'block' });
        $(window).load(function () {
            loader.css({ 'display': 'none' });
        });
    });
```

It works correctly (I need some more tests) for now. Do you have any ideas or better way for this?
Thanks!

EDIT:
this is not correct solution, because when modal is loaded, and I show loaded modal, page is not loading any content..