# Fade in elements after they've been created with Jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I want to append a bunch of images to a div using Jquery:

```
elements = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

  elements = elements + '<img src=img' + i + '>';

}

$('#container').append(elements);
```

This looks terrible because it's showing each img being loaded one by one. Instead, I want to fade them in once all of them are loaded and rendered. They MUST be faded in together, not one by one.

I have tried:

```
$('#container').append(elements).hide(0).fadeIn(2000);
```

But that seems to start the fade in at the beginning of the process, not the end.

Any ideas from you good people? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about fading in after appending the images, but after all the images are loaded. Use `.load()` to check if images are loaded.

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brQrXV

I used code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893943

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  elements = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    elements = elements + '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/' + i + '" class="appended">';
  }
  $('#container').append(elements);
  
  var $images = $('.appended');
  var loaded_images_count = 0;
  $images.load(function(){
    loaded_images_count++;
    if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
      $('#container').addClass('loaded');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1500ms ease;
}
#container.loaded img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this is great. Now a slight modification to my original question: each element is accompanied by an <h1> that I want to fade in simultaneously with all the images. When the images are cached, they start fading in and then the <h1>s jump in mid-fade. Applying the .appended class to a div around the <h1> and <img> doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to first preload all the images, then add them and fade them in when they have all loaded.

```
var deferreds = [];
var elements  = $.map(Array(9).fill(0), function(_,i) {
  var img = new Image();
  var def = $.Deferred();

  img.onload = def.resolve;
  img.src = 'img' + i + '.png';
  deferreds.push(def.promise());
  return img;
});

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
    $(elements).hide().appendTo('#container').fadeIn(1000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo! Is this in some way superior to @DimSum's answer? Because it contains some functions I am not familiar with, so the other answer is easier to understand for me.

Comment: @TonaldDrump From my understanding, the difference is: this answer is doing "check loaded > append > fade", while mine is doing "append > check loaded > fade".

Answer (score 0):

Append them all at first with a `display:none` style. After that give to all of them `fadeIn()`;